# Unnamed return variable can remain unassigned. Add an explicit return with value to all non-reverting code paths or name the variable; error in line 4

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity >= 0.7.0 < 0.9.0;

library search {
function findIt(uint [] storage numb, uint value) public view returns(uint){
    for (uint i = 0; i < numb.length; i++) if (numb[1] == value) return i;
}  
  }

 contract test{
 uint [] data;
  constructor() {
    data.push(1);
    data.push(2);
    data.push(3);
    data.push(4);
    data.push(5);
}

function getVal(uint val) public view returns(uint){
    uint result = search.findIt(data,val);
    return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you indent the code properly

```
 function findIt(uint [] storage numb, uint value) public view returns(uint){
      for (uint i = 0; i < numb.length; i++)
           if (numb[1] == value)
                return i;
 }
```

It immediately obvious that the case where value isn't present in the numb array doesn't return an explicit uint.

An option is revert.

```
 function findIt(uint [] storage numb, uint value) public view returns(uint){
      for (uint i = 0; i < numb.length; i++)
           if (numb[1] == value)
                return i;
      revert("Invalid value");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i have never used `library`,

a short and working codes of what u want to do:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity >0.8.0 <0.9.0;

contract Test {
   uint[] data=[1,2,3,4,5];
   function isValuePresent(uint value) external view returns(uint){
      for (uint i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        if (data[i] == value) return i;
      return 1;
   }
}
```